# get file content from url, then extract keywords

Tags: php, json

I have this json page:
 https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=9789264187061
which looks like this:

> {  "kind": "books#volumes",  "totalItems": 1,  "items": [   {
>   "kind": "books#volume",    "id": "Z9i0nRGVYrcC",    "etag":
>   "6BZ/vrmjoqQ",    "selfLink":
>   "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/Z9i0nRGVYrcC",
>   "volumeInfo": {
>       "title": "Innovative Clusters",
>       "subtitle": "Drivers of National Innovation Systems",
>       "authors": [
>        "Pim Den Hertog",
>        "Svend Reme",
>        "OECD - Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development"
>       ],
>       "publisher": "Organization for Economic",
>       "publishedDate": "2001",
>       "description": "The growth potential of countries increasingly depends on the effectiveness of their innovation systems in creating,
>   diffusing and using knowledge. A large share of market-based or
>   informal knowledge flows occur within industrial clusters that can be
>   seen as reduced-form innovation systems. Policies to stimulate
>   innovation at national and local levels must both build on and
>   contribute to the dynamics of innovative clusters. This book presents
>   a series of papers written by policy makers and academic experts in
>   the field, that demonstrate why and how this can be done in different
>   national contexts.",
>       "industryIdentifiers": [
>        {
>         "type": "ISBN_10",
>         "identifier": "9264187065"
>        },
>        {
>         "type": "ISBN_13",
>         "identifier": "9789264187061"
>        }
>       ],
>       "pageCount": 419,
>       "printType": "BOOK",
>       "categories": [
>        "Business & Economics"
>       ],
>       "averageRating": 1.0,
>       "ratingsCount": 1,
>       "contentVersion": "1.0.1.0.preview.2",
>       "imageLinks": {
>        "smallThumbnail": "http://bks6.books.google.it/books?id=Z9i0nRGVYrcC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
>        "thumbnail": "http://bks6.books.google.it/books?id=Z9i0nRGVYrcC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
>       },
>       "language": "en",
>       "previewLink": "http://books.google.it/books?id=Z9i0nRGVYrcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=9789264187061&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api",
>       "infoLink": "http://books.google.it/books?id=Z9i0nRGVYrcC&dq=9789264187061&hl=&source=gbs_api",
>       "canonicalVolumeLink": "http://books.google.it/books/about/Innovative_Clusters.html?hl=&id=Z9i0nRGVYrcC"
>   },    "saleInfo": {
>       "country": "IT",
>       "saleability": "NOT_FOR_SALE",
>       "isEbook": false    },    "accessInfo": {
>       "country": "IT",
>       "viewability": "ALL_PAGES",
>       "embeddable": true,
>       "publicDomain": false,
>       "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY",
>       "epub": {
>        "isAvailable": true,
>        "acsTokenLink": "http://books.google.it/books/download/Innovative_Clusters-sample-epub.acsm?id=Z9i0nRGVYrcC&format=epub&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api"
>       },
>       "pdf": {
>        "isAvailable": false
>       },
>       "webReaderLink": "http://books.google.it/books/reader?id=Z9i0nRGVYrcC&hl=&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&source=gbs_api",
>       "accessViewStatus": "SAMPLE"    },    "searchInfo": {
>       "textSnippet": "This book presents a series of papers written by policy makers and academic experts in the field, that demonstrate why
>   and how this can be done in different national contexts."    }   }  ]
>   }

I have to read it and define
 $book_title and $book_author

> "volumeInfo": {
>       "title": "Innovative Clusters",
>       "authors": [
>        "Pim Den Hertog",
>        "Svend Reme",

according to the code above

> echo $book_title;

should return 'Innovative Clusters'
and

> echo $book_author;

should return 'Pim Den Hertog and Svend Reme'

Comment: seems like "do my job" question.

Comment: I tried fopen and file_get_contents

Comment: I am a newbie, maybe you can suggest me what functions to use

Comment: [json_decode()](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) springs to mind

Comment: like Dagon said, json_decode it and walk the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [link](http://webhole.net/2009/08/31/how-to-read-json-data-with-php/). Don't expect people to do your homework, study  that code a little bit and you will find answer in less then 10 minutes. Basically when you decode json you will get object or array depending on what you want. So if you do this

```
   $data=json_decode($str);//$str is your json string
   foreach($data->items as $item){
      foreach($item as $bookdata){
         if(is_object($bookdata) && isset($bookdata->title)){
                echo $bookdata->title ; 
              }
           } 
        }
```

I am leaving it to you to figure out how to get authors ;) Combine this and previous answer and you are there

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) function.
As first argument put your `json` code (or var), the second if is set to `true` will return an associative array.

```
$file = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=9789264187061');
$json = json_decode($file, true);

print_r($json);
```

That's a good point to start.

Comment: how to read the text from the url? thx

Comment: @alle that's included in the code above